# C# DateTime Extension Method

Tags: c#, datetime

I was asked to extend the type DateTime by Extension Method.
Then i need to create a method that will check if the month value added is my birth day, and if not it will tell me how many months left till my birth day.
I tried to create the following class for the DateTime extention, with the extension method inside.

I just got lost with the birth day month calculation inside that method

Should be something like:

```
public static class MyDateTimeExtension
{
    public static DateTime Month(this DateTime DiffDT)
    {
        DateTime BirthdayMonth;
        DateTime CurrentMonth;
        return DiffDT = BirthdayMonth - CurrentMonth;
    }
}
```

or something like

```
        return DiffDT.AddMonths = BirthdayMonth.AddMonths - CurrentMonth.AddMonths;
```

But ofcourse this code can't compile.
After creating the extension methos i should call the method from the main class with new DateTime variable

```
 DateTime DT;
 Console.WriteLine(DT.Month());
```

Hope this helps to understand

Comment: Unclear for me, how can you express month with `DateTime` ?  provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: I don't know how can i express month with DateTime... if can't with DateTime i don't even know what else should i use

Comment: Fine, you've not answered my another question. Provide some sample input and expected output. Edit your question with this info.

Comment: Edit done... hope this is clear enough for understand what i mean

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To implement this logic, I made the extension method check if the month is later in the year, and if so, add 12 to the difference for the wrap around logic. Here is the extension method:

```
public static int DateTimeMonth(this DateTime dt, DateTime birthday)
{
    int difference = birthday.Month - dt.Month;
    if (difference < 0)
    {
        difference += 12;
    }
    return difference;
}
```

And here is the code in main to use this method:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime birthday = new DateTime(1985, 03, 22);
int monthDifference = today.DateTimeMonth(birthday);
if (monthDifference == 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("It is your birthday month this month!");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("It will be your birthday in " + monthDifference + " months.");
}
```

The extension method returns an integer that can be used in the caller, but if you just want the string that says what is being printed in the WriteLines, you can have the extension method perform this logic instead and return that string.

Answer (score 3):

To implement this logic, I made the extension method as shown below, check it out,if it may be helpful for you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string date = "1987/7/2";
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

        string diffDate =  MyDateTimeExtension.GetDiffDate(dt);       
        string[] words = diffDate.Split('/');

        if (Convert.ToInt32(words[1])== 0 && Convert.ToInt32(words[2])== 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Today is your Birthday");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are " + words[0] + " Year/s " +  words[1] + " Month/s " +  words[2] + " Day/s");
        }
    }
}

public static class MyDateTimeExtension
{
    public static string GetDiffDate(this DateTime dtt)
    {
       int intYear, intMonth, intDay;

        DateTime td = DateTime.Now;
        int leapYear = 0;
        for (int i = dtt.Year; i < td.Year; i++)
        {
            if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(i))
            {
                ++leapYear;
            }
        }

        TimeSpan timespan = td.Subtract(dtt);

        intDay = timespan.Days - leapYear;
        int intResult = 0;

        intYear = Math.DivRem(intDay, 365, out intResult);
        intMonth = Math.DivRem(intResult, 30, out intResult);
        intDay = intResult;

        string dateFormat= String.Format(intYear.ToString() + "/" + intMonth + "/" + intDay);   
        return dateFormat;
    }
}
```